# MapKit lines and polygons

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I have a map and line (poly-line) on it. I'm trying to make a smooth polygon around this line. The problem I'm facing is how to create that polygon look smooth with rounded ends. any suggestions/solutions?
I've tried to draw another line over existing one with different thickness, but it doesn't work well with zooming...

Answer (score 0):

In MKOverlayPathView which is a superclass of MKPolylineView there is a property called lineCap. Set it to

`kCGLineCapRound`

check here: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayPathView_class/Reference/Reference.html

Hope it helps.